# How do I concatenate a vector of strings in c++ with boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a vector of strings, like this:

```
{"abc"}{"def"}{"ghi"}
```

I want to concatenate them into a single string, with a separator like "-".

Is there a concise (pretty) way of doing this without using a typical for loop? I have c++03 and boost available to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, boost provides a convenient algorithm for achieving what you are trying to do. In higher level languages you may have spotted a join function. Boost provides an equivalent algorithm in the join function.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
using namespace std;

string data[] = {"abc","def","ghi"};
const size_t data_size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
vector<string> stringVector(data, data + data_size);
string joinedString = boost::algorithm::join(stringVector, "-");
```

Comment: `boost::as_array` might be helpful

Comment: Also `const string[] data` doesn't look like valid C++ to me.

Comment: @Mehrdad I've remove the const. Valid now.

Comment: Er I didn't mean the `const`, I meant it should be `string data[]` not `string[] data`...

Comment: Ah, must have been a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, there is currently a proposal for `std::join`, which you can check out [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3594.html).

But since you have boost available, you can use `boost::algorithm::join`, which takes a sequence of strings and a separator, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> words;
  words.push_back("abc");
  words.push_back("def");
  words.push_back("ghi");
  std::string result = boost::algorithm::join(words, "-");
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
abc-def-ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using only the STL is:

```
std::ostringstream result;
if (my_vector.size()) {
    std::copy(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end()-1,
              std::ostream_iterator<string>(result, "-"));

    result << my_vector.back();
}

return result.str()
```